# Is it appropriate on RLU to ask for tutorials in private beta

Tags: discussion

Before you can ask your first question in private beta you get a note what to do and what to neglect. Amongst other things it says:

> Avoid “easy” questions
>
> It’s tempting to start with easy, superficial questions: surveys, polls, and rudimentary questions like “what are some good books on this topic” or “what are the best blogs on this topic.” Those are not good questions for the private beta – they don’t reflect the actual content that we want this site to contain, and are not representative of it.

I don't know Russian yet. Just a couple of sentences that a friend told me. But I am eager to learn the language a bit, in order to survive if I travel to Russia ;)

Thus I signed up to that page, but if I've nothing in hand to work with it's actually hard to get started both learning the language and supporting this page by asking good questions.

So, actually I'm looking for tutorials about Russian language containing video and/or audio examples to learn the pronunciation and I don't know why that shouldn't be a question in private beta. I'm pretty sure that I'm not the only one who signed up for getting started. Thus, is such a question - disregarded of the hint above - an acceptable question for the main page? What are alternatives? Asking on meta? Waiting until private beta ends?

Answer (score 3):

Such a list of sources will be compiled sooner or later. For example, StackOverflow contains lists of books on certain topics in a limited number of questions ([C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/45668), [C books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/45668)). It's not good if a lot of the questions ask for a list of books, but a single question like the ones I mentioned above is fine, I think. The private beta will end pretty soon, by the way.

Comment: So, how does this single question find its way on that page? Is it appropriate to create that question now, flag for moderator review so that it become community wiki and some experts will edit the post by adding sources?

Comment: @Em1 You don't have to flag the question, it will become the community wiki in a natural way. There are [a lot of ways](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/45668) for the question to become a community wiki, don't worry about this.

Comment: That means, you (also) support the idea of creating a single question sooner rather than later?

Comment: @Em1 Of course, I said so in the first sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that unlike other SE communities we allow posting links to the resources and questions thereof. Since being able to share/find a good source of information is essential for learning.

Comment: Some sites even have tags such as `resource-request` or `resources` or `online-resources` for such questions.

Answer (score 0):

We could do something similar to what I did on the Chinese SE with this [list of resources](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1120/43).

Comment: I think that's similar to the suggestion of Malcolm. Would you start creating such a community wiki? Alternatively I could create a post, but not before tomorrow. Maybe we could even combine the ideas from your list of resources on Chinese SE with those as for the C++ books (as given in Malcom's answer).

Comment: Oh, I see right now that you're not moderator on here, therefore you're also not able to create a wiki post. Unfortunately I can't provide any appropriate sources yet, to start such a post. Maybe we could collect a handful of resources first, and then create a wiki post with help of some moderators.

Comment: @Em1 That's a good idea! :) Or we can start collecting resources and wait for when we'll have pro-tem mods. :)

Comment: Fine. There's just one open question: Where do we collect? Do we use my question above. I am not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: @Em1 Which question? This one?

Comment: Yes. Or do you have any better ideas?

Comment: Keep this one for the "Do we do it or not?" discussion. Open another one for the other thing. This is my suggestion. :D

Answer (score 0):

Private beta stage is for setting up the site and attract users to it. I believe that as long as such tutorials are requested and useful, it's a valid question. I would suggest compiling a list in the wiki, however this can be done later. For now it's fine to just tag the questions, to be able to collect them later.