# Collecting sources for learning Russian - community wiki on main

Tags: discussion, proposal, community-wiki

According to the responses to my question about [Is it appropriate on RLU to ask for tutorials in private beta](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/60/109) we should create a community wiki post which contains a collection of tutorials, blogs and books about the Russian language.

First of all, there were two proposals how to design them ([1st like here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242) and [2nd like here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1120)). I personally tend to the 2nd layout.

Secondly, before we set up the community wiki we should collect at least a few sources to start with, so that the first version of that community wiki is already usable. A good start would also prevent the community wiki could founder.

Thus, I started collecting a few on-line resources which looks appropriate to me:

In English:

- http://masterrussian.com/
- http://learningrussian.net/ (incl. audio)
- http://www.russianlessons.net/ (incl. audio)
- http://www.elanguageschool.net/russian (incl. videos)
- http://www.russian-plus.com/ (incl. videos)

In Russian:

- http://www.learnrussianweb.com/  (blog)

What is YOUR part now?

- Please provide more resources.
- If any of the already provided resources is too bad, feel free to remove it.
- If you disagree with choosing the 2nd layout (see above), then - um - start a discussion ;)
- Please comment if there is anything else missing in here yet?

---

Last but not least, I am not aware of there is already any moderator here (if yes, who is it) who is able to make the question community wiki from the beginning. (I know that a question [becomes cw for different reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741), but if the activity is too rare then it may take a too long time until it becomes cw).

---

What is missing yet?

- Dictionaries

  - Russian-Russian (definition, incl. pronunciation/IPA)
  - Russian-English (definition)
  - Russian-English (translation)
  - regional words (Ukraine, Belarus, ...) (like American, British, Australian English) (example [American English dictionary](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/))
  - Etymology
  - idioms
  - Slang
- Books

  - for beginner, intermediate and professionals
  - on-line versions, e-books
- other on-line resources (wikipedia, wiktionary)

Comment: How is community wiki created?

Comment: We don't have admins yet. AFAIK, an admin needs >1000 reputation (http://russian.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools). We'll have some soon hence: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10848/russian-language-usage

Comment: @texnic I think the link in my post should answer how a cw is created. It needs a lot of edits or answer, but I think the better way is that a moderator changes it status early. ... About moderators. I don't think that a moderator needs those rep (for a new site). He's getting privileges by his moderators status, and I guess is selected by the community. Stackoverflow currently does [have a election](http://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1).

Comment: @Em1 The pro-tem moderators are not selected by the community. You propose yourself or someone else, and the Team will choose. We'll have an election after we graduate.

Comment: Right now we (the community team at Stack Exchange) are acting as your moderators until we [select a few folks](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) from the community here in a few weeks. If anything needs doing that requires moderator privileges, just raise a flag on a post or ask a question here on meta and let us know. :)

Comment: Oh, @AnnaLear is watching over us! :D